# SWT Custom FontDialog

Tags: java, swt, jfxpanel

I want to  restrict the size selection or hide the size Selction block in FontDiallog, i know this is standard widget we cant customize with this standard FontDialog.
Is their any other way to do with customization?

Comment: FontDialog looks completely different on each platform and can't be customized.

Comment: Is their any open source on custom FontDialog for SWT?